# C++ SQLite3 how to know if select return 0 rows

Tags: c++, sqlite

C++ SQLite3 how to know if select return 0 rows

I have a select statement for SQLite3, how do I know that if after executing the sql statement, the result is 0 rows , no match found etc..

How can i modify my code so that if 0 rows found, it will not execute the part where it put the result into a vector.

My code below:

```
sqlstatement = "SELECT * from abe_account where department="+quotesql(department)+" AND name="+quotesql(name)+";";


    std::vector< std::vector < std:: string > > result;
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    result.push_back(std::vector< std::string >());


    sqlite3_prepare( db, sqlstatement.c_str() , -1, &stmt2, NULL );//preparing the statement
    sqlite3_step( stmt2 );//executing the statement

    while( sqlite3_column_text( stmt2, 0 ) )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    result[i].push_back( std::string( (char *)sqlite3_column_text( stmt2, i ) ) );
    sqlite3_step( stmt2 );
    counter ++;
}
```

Comment: Just check return code of `sqlite3_step`... And RTFM.

Comment: what return code am i looking for? i know 101 is execute successfully

Comment: are you referring to "SQLITE_EMPTY"

Comment: @baokychen: `SQLITE_ROW` indicates that there is a row; `SQLITE_DONE` indicates that the query is done and there are no more rows. This is described in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sqlite3_step` returns `SQLITE_DONE` when there are no (more) rows to process:

```
int stat = sqlite3_step(stmt2);
if (stat == SQLITE_DONE) {
    // no rows to process
}
```

Remember to check for errors as well, e.g.:

```
if (stat != SQLITE_DONE && stat != SQLITE_ROW) {
    // there's probably a problem
}
```

You can find the [complete list of result codes in the manual](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#SQLITE_ABORT).

Lastly, you should use the "v2" interface when using SQLite3. [From the manual](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_prepare):

> The sqlite3_prepare_v2() and sqlite3_prepare16_v2() interfaces are recommended for all new programs. The two older interfaces are retained for backwards compatibility, but their use is discouraged.

Comment: I just wanna check if SQLite found any rows, if no row , return boolean success=false else success=true

Comment: @baokychen: Did you read the answer? The first sentence I wrote is exactly what you need.

Comment: The problem is that when you do that check, the first row is stepped, and you cannot work on it. How can you check if there is rows or not without pass the first line of the search ?

Answer (score 0):

Do a SQL Count first, if it returns 0 you can just stop execution without needing to query the select statement.

Comment: How do i do a SQL count & check its return is 0

Comment: The result from the query should put an int as a result.  That int will be the count.  if (result[0] > 0){ //continue}